# What is the most efficient way of finding the ranks of one numpy array in another?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

Say I have two arrays:

```
a = np.array([2, 5, 4, 3, 1])
b = np.array([4.5, 1.5, 3.5])
```

I want to find the rank of each element of `a` if it were in `b`. So this would be the desired output:

```
[1, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

The following code technically works for small arrays but is extremely slow if `a` and `b` are 10,000+ in size:

```
ranks = [rankdata(b + [i])[-1] - 1 for i in a]
```

What is the most efficient way of achieving this result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html#numpy-searchsorted)

```
ind = np.argsort(y)
np.searchsorted(y, x, sorter=ind)
# array([1, 3, 2, 1, 0], dtype=int64)
```

If `y` has duplicates, you may have to tinker with the `side` argument.